# how to bring an ImageView to top on its Click in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, bringtofront

I have 5 custome ImageViews,I want to make a collage app demo,So for that i want to bring front particular imageView to front when its tapped,I have tried **bringtoFront** method for that but its not working,So can anybuddy Please help me to solve this issue,My xml and java code is as below

**xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_hdr" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collageBgView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#191919" />

        <PhotoLib.CollageView
            android:id="@+id/collageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <PhotoLib.CollageView
            android:id="@+id/collageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <PhotoLib.CollageView
            android:id="@+id/collageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <PhotoLib.CollageView
            android:id="@+id/collageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <PhotoLib.CollageView
            android:id="@+id/collageView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <PhotoLib.CollageView
            android:id="@+id/collageView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <PhotoLib.CollageView
            android:id="@+id/collageView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**java**

```
RelativeLayout rl_main;
cl1 = (CollageView) findViewById(R.id.collageView1);
cl2 = (CollageView) findViewById(R.id.collageView2);
cl3 = (CollageView) findViewById(R.id.collageView3);
cl4 = (CollageView) findViewById(R.id.collageView4);
collageBgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.collageBgView);
rl_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_main);

findViewById(R.id.collageView1).setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cl1.bringToFront();
                cl2.invalidate();
                cl3.invalidate();
                cl4.invalidate();
                rl_main.invalidate();

            }
        });
findViewById(R.id.collageView2).setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cl2.bringToFront();
                cl1.invalidate();
                cl3.invalidate();
                cl4.invalidate();
                rl_main.invalidate();

            }
        });
findViewById(R.id.collageView3).setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cl3.bringToFront();
                cl2.invalidate();
                cl1.invalidate();
                cl4.invalidate();
                rl_main.invalidate();

            }
        });
findViewById(R.id.collageView4).setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cl4.bringToFront();
                cl2.invalidate();
                cl3.invalidate();
                cl1.invalidate();
                rl_main.invalidate();

            }
        });

cl1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cl1.bringToFront();
        cl2.invalidate();
        cl3.invalidate();
        cl4.invalidate();
        rl_main.invalidate();
        return false;
    }
});
cl2.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cl2.bringToFront();
        cl1.invalidate();
        cl3.invalidate();
        cl4.invalidate();
        rl_main.invalidate();
        return false;
    }
});
cl3.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cl3.bringToFront();
        cl2.invalidate();
        cl1.invalidate();
        cl4.invalidate();
        rl_main.invalidate();
        return false;
    }
});
cl4.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cl4.bringToFront();
        cl2.invalidate();
        cl3.invalidate();
        cl1.invalidate();
        rl_main.invalidate();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use:

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    cl1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cl3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cl4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rl_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });
```

you are using relativelayout so just hiding should work for you if your ImageView are not to big. Be careful when using to many imagens could give you memory problems

Comment: i dont want to make visibility gone of other imageViews..!!! i just want selected image to bring front..!

Comment: but they are overlayed rigth? so just one at the time apears?

Comment: Its my custom ImageView,Which can freely move in whole screen on its touch ,You seen photocollage? just like that.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake i misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes...no problem,SO have you any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just use only `yourView.bringToFront()` method for the view you want bring front in relative layout.

Comment: Havent you seen my question completely?i already have used it..!

Comment: Haven't you seen my answer properly! I just said to use only and only  bringToFront() method, remove invalidate().